# Java - rectangle getBounds();

Tags: java, rectangles

Today I decided to make a top down based game using Java. I have already made the window and included the Jframe. But I found a problem on creating the GameObject in the Rectagle GetBounds(); . I don't know what really is because I am a beginner and I know the basics of java :( .

If anyone can help me to resolve this problem I give the code example below:

```
package example;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import java.awt.Rectangle;

public abstract class GameObject {
protected int x, y;
protected float velX = 0, velY = 0;

public GameObject(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public abstract void tick();
public abstract void render(Graphics g);
public abstract void Rectangle getBounds();

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public float getVelX() {
    return velX;
}

public void setVelX(float velX) {
    this.velX = velX;
}

public float getVelY() {
    return velY;
}

public void setVelY(float velY) {
    this.velY = velY;
}
}
```

The code causes the following errors:

> Illegal modifier for the field Rectangle; only public, protected,
>   private, static, final, transient & volatile are permitted Return type
>   for the method is missing  Syntax error, insert ";" to complete
>   FieldDeclaration   This method requires a body instead of a semicolon 
>   void is an invalid type for the variable Rectangle

*Note:* I'm using Java SE-8 and Eclipse Oxigen.

Comment: If `getBounds()` returns a `Rectangle` it should not have `void`.

Comment: `void` and `Rectangle` are both return types of `getBounds`. A method can't have multiple return types.

Comment: `public abstract void Rectangle getBounds();` should be `public abstract Rectangle getBounds();`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an instance of GameObject (like this: new GameObject()) then GameObject class must not be abstract.

You cannot create an instance of abstract class. You can only create a class that inherits from abstract class and implements all or some methods.

Here you can either implement methods tick(), render(Graphics g) and getBounds() or create a new class that inherits from GameObject (public class GameObjectImp extends GameObject) and implement methods there.

Comment: This appears to be unrelated to the errors shown in the question, and thus does not answer the question. The class and methods are declared abstract, no body was provided for the abstract methods - I don't see any evidence here that OP doesn't know what abstract means.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, sorry but i don't know how to explain better what i want to do, i found some videos tutorial to make a top-down shooter, if you want to see the tutorial: https://youtu.be/Px6d_i46GbA

**The problem to me starts at: 6:00**

Comment: @c56edfrq The `getBounds` method in that video doesn't have `void` in the signature.

Comment: I was i little confused with some things, im sorry to all people replied to my question xD.